# Way to capture a callout as an image in quarto

Tags: css, quarto

Is there any way to capture, from the qmd itself, an image of a callout like this one below? So if I had this qmd:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

::: {.callout-note}

### Date

```{r}
#| results: asis
#| echo: false

cat(format(Sys.Date(), "%b %d"))
```

:::
````

I'd like it output an image like this as a png:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `capture` package (not on cran), however, the quality is quite low of the png. I added an additional empty space (`<br>`) in order to have the full callout in the image created.

````
---
format: html
---

<div id="calloutdiv">

::: {.callout-note}

### Date

```{r}
#| results: asis
#| echo: false

cat(format(Sys.Date(), "%b %d"))
```
:::
<br>
</div>

```{r}
  capture::capture(
    selector = "#calloutdiv",
    filename = "callout.png",
     "Take screenshot of callout", 
  button_class = "btn btn-primary btn-block"
  )
```
````

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

[image]